# How to save Discord chat history

Tags: chat, discord

How do I save the chat history from Discord?

There are some messages with valuable information and I'd like to make a backup copy.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

You can use [the browser version of Discord History Tracker](https://dht.chylex.com/browser-only/). There are several options to choose from: userscript, console, or bookmarklet.

Then you can save [the viewer file](https://dht.chylex.com/browser-only/build/viewer.html) to your computer to view the saved history.

Use a different Discord account for this when possible.

#### Option 2

To save several messages to PDF:

- Open a browser (the instructions are for Google Chrome but probably work in other browsers).
- Go to https://discord.com/app
- Navigate to the messages you want to save.
- Select several messages (press the left mouse button somewhere in the chat, except on a clickable link such as a username, and drag from there). If you select too many messages, some of them will become temporarily invisible in the process, because Discord shows only a few messages at a time. Instead, select a few messages (and later repeat the steps for other messages).
- Click on the address bar, so that the browser's hotkeys rather than Discord's hotkeys become active.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the Print dialog.
- Click *More settings* → *Selection only*. This prevents menus from obstructing the view.
- Select *Destination: Save to PDF*.
- Click *Save*.

#### Option 3

You can use [DiscordChatExporter](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/DiscordChatExporter/releases).

Use a different Discord account for this when possible.

It is advised to read the FAQ [here](https://www.downloadsource.net/how-to-download-discord-channel-and-direct-message-dm-history/n/14222/) first.

#### Option 4

You can use [the desktop app called Discord History Tracker](https://dht.chylex.com/).

Use a different Discord account for this when possible.

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/self-answer

Comment: While answering your own question is perfectly acceptable it is preferred that you [have only one single answer](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3400/why-please-only-post-one-answer-to-a-question) per question.

Comment: @Mokubai It is not always preferred. Each answer is a separate solution. Merging answers depending on *who* wrote them is discrimination against the answerer. See [this answer](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3430/498103).

Comment: If the solutions are wildly different then maybe, but all your answers are nothing more than a variation of "use this other app". The answer you linked says "one answer per person per question" and then says that there ***might*** be exceptions for *radically* different solutions ***sometimes***. Your solutions are not "radically" different, they are just "here's another app that does the same thing." In general we prefer the "one person, one answer" and there is no discrimination against any one person.

Comment: See also [When should I add another answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125751/when-should-i-add-another-answer) which says "If you can offer substantially different answers to the problem, that can be a case where multiple separate answers are appropriate, but each should be able to stand by its own merits, of course. *Variations of the same theme belong in the same post, making more than one answer of them just adds noise.*"

Comment: @Mokubai All solutions will achieve roughly the same goal because they answer a question about that goal. But they achieve that by doing radically different things. If you put all my answers into the category "here's another app", then well, this is a site about software, so of course software is involved. But the Google Chrome answer is NOT about a dedicated app; Discord History Tracker saves to file; some solutions use web apps, some use desktop apps, some don't use a dedicated app. Substantially different solutions. **These are not "variations of the same theme". This is not "noise".**

Comment: @Mokubai The file from Discord History Tracker is incompatible with other answers. These are substantially different answers. Please undelete them.